# <size> attribute not useful when using layer-list?

Tags: android

Given I have a background drawable to create bulletpoints for TextViews like this:

[image: Example of what I want]

Then my XML code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="235dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <padding android:left="10dp" />
            <size android:height="5dp" android:width="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/my_pink"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <padding android:left="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But once I use the code shown above, my bullet points look like this:

[image: Result of the XML shown above]

It seems the `<size>` tag is ignored completely.

How would you solve this problem? Using a 9patch, yes I know.. perhaps that's the easiest to do.. but in fact I was hoping to find a XML solution as it's more flexible in the future.

Custom drawing is also out of the question.

Comment: Look my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841517/layer-list-ignore-size-tag/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<size>` tag certainly works in `layer-list`
and to show the bullet points for textviews you can use the xml attribute `android:drawableLeft`
-> [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft)

With this approach, there is no need of 9-patch and custom drawing.

Posting code & screenshot here for the reference.

**res/drawable/bullet_point_layer.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:right="3dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <padding android:left="10dp" />
        <size android:height="10dp" android:width="10dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#ff0080"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

**res/layout/main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView one"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bullet_point_layer"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView Two"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bullet_point_layer"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**How it looks** 
[image]

Comment: That is certainly a good solution. Didn't think about drawableLeft before. Thank you!

Comment: @Vijay C: <size> tag is working or not in layer-list ?? you told "<size> tag certainly works in layer-list", I have also problem in RatingsBar like this bullet point, star getting stretched vertically, is there any way to set height to wrap_content ??

Comment: @Jayesh have you used the drawableLeft ?

Comment: @VijayC: actually my query is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519712/ratingbar-getting-streched-when-setting-drawble

Answer (score 6):

This is an old post but I thought I would add something very important which is missing on this post.

From my experience the last item of the `<layer-list>` will be the item which the size value is taken from.

So in this example I create a two line divider line. I specify an empty item at the end to specify the divider drawable height.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#535353" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="@dimen/common_divider_line_half_size">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#737373" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Last item empty to specify divider height -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="@dimen/common_divider_line_size"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Set the ImageView scaleType to fitXY, this way you don't have to set the dimensions. The following will work:
<layer-list ...>
<item android:drawable="@color/some_color"/>
<item><bitmap android:src="..." android:gravity="center" /></item>
</layer-list>

Comment: No. Below Android 21, either size tag or android:width/height attributes are ignored by the system.