# RatingBar getting stretched when setting drawable

Tags: android, ratingbar

When I am setting progressDrawable to RatingBar its display streched like below image,

[image]

xml code is:

> ```
> <RatingBar
> android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
> android:layout_width="wrap_content"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:isIndicator="true"
> android:numStars="5"
> android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingstars"
> android:stepSize="1.0" />
> ```

ratingstars.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
> <item
>     android:id="@+android:id/background"
>     android:drawable="@drawable/starfullgray"/>
> <item
>     android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
>     android:drawable="@drawable/starfullgray"/>
> <item
>     android:id="@+android:id/progress"
>     android:drawable="@drawable/starfull"/>
> </layer-list>
> ```

how to set Ratings Star height to wrap_content by any way ??

Comment: Have you tried adding an extra transparent pixel to the most bottom area of the image? What does that do?

Comment: How to add an extra pixel to the most bottom area of Image ? I am not getting you